# How to find when a previous flight occured?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, us-airways

I want information about a flight in 2009. My dad came to Canada from the US.  He went back in August 2009.  He forgets the exact date.  He travelled by US airways.  He need to know exact date for citizen purpose.  Can anyone help me to find this information?

Comment: The information may be stamped in his passport.

Comment: How was the ticket purchased? Online? Travel agent?

Comment: I'm not sure the marked duplicate is actually a duplicate. This question is asking for evidence that a person flew on a certain flight, not historical information on the flight itself. Can't really help; I've often wanted to be able to access that information when I need to do a frequent flyer retro claim! Try calling US Airways and see what they say. BTW, US Airways is merging with American Airlines, *not* United Airlines.

Comment: yes, calling the airline is the most logical thing to do. Maybe customs also has it logged, who knows what they record and how long they keep it when you hand over your papers at entry, but try to get anything out of the government...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if he got a stamp in his passport, that may be the easiest - have a look through his passport for entry stamps for August 2009, and that may give you the answer you're after.

Second option - try US Airways. With his full name, some other proof of ID, they may be able to locate the flight.

Thirdly - did he use a travel agency? They'll likely still have a record of the transaction.

Finally, if you contact [Canadian Border Services](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/menu-eng.html) they may have a way of identifying the date of travel, as there would be a record of him crossing their border.

Most of these will probably require some proof of ID, to be fair, but it should be possible to identify.